# Java Netbeans DB Connection error

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, mysql-workbench

I am new in Netbeans.  I am trying to making a new project on Store Management by Netbeans and mysql workbench as my DB. But I am facing problem in connecting database. Here my codes are given:

```
    enter code here
package MyDb.utils;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



public class DbConnection {
     private static Connection conn=null;
    static{
        Throwable e = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try {
                System.out.println("Connecting Database!!");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GanpatiDB","root","");
                System.out.println("");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            System.out.println("Terminating application...check database");
            System.exit(0);
        }
         finally {
    System.out.println("Closing the connection.");

}
    }
    private static Object connection;


public DbConnection(){

    }
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        return conn;
    }
    public static void closeConnection() throws Exception{

        conn.close();
    }


}
```

After debugging the project the console gives the result as

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) 
>   But still it is showing some errors as below:

```
    Jan 14, 2014 1:47:13 PM MyDb.utils.DbConnection <clinit>
Terminating application...check database
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'GanpatiDB[root on Default schema]'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4004)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2312)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at MyDb.utils.DbConnection.<clinit>(DbConnection.java:20)
    at desktopapplication1.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:27)
    at desktopapplication1.NewJFrame$2.run(NewJFrame.java:199)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: remember any connection with database is not the business of `IDE`, IDE is just a coding and compiling platform, which will not compile the code itself.

Comment: Can you please guide me in getting the permission

Comment: as the error prompted `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`, please check the syntax of connection

Comment: try to use the following :  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build is showing up as successful for a good reason: you are catching the actual error and making the log statement yourself:

> `catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
>
>           Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
>
>           System.out.println("Terminating application...check database");
>
>           System.exit(0);
>
>   }`

Because it is catching the error, the code executes as expected (if you want it to show up as failed, you should change the parameter for `System.exit` to -1).

The error you're catching is a `ClassNotFoundException`, Java seems unable to find the MySQL driver you're trying to find using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`. If you look at the logs, there is no mention of the driver at all, which seems to support this theory.

Comment: Thank you , my database connection is done but now another error occurs:        "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at desktopapplication1.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:27)
 at desktopapplication1.NewJFrame$2.run(NewJFrame.java:199)"

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough information for me to work with. It looks to me like your JFrame has a faulty event listener or something in its init method.